# Rewrite conditions in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a sitemap for my multistore magento website. So each shop-view has it's own sitemap. Therefore I have made

sitemap/store_en/sitemap.xml

sitemap/store_de/sitemap.xml

sitemap/store_nl/sitemap.xml

What I'm trying to achieve is to redirect on request of mydomain.nl/sitemap.xml to  mydomain.nl/sitemap/store_nl/sitemap.xml

This I have put in my htaccess file. But this doesn't work. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
##rewrite rule for de sitemaps

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*mydomain.nl$
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ /sitemap/store_nl/sitemap.xml [NC]
```

I have another rewrite rule. I don't know if it is of any influence...

```
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)\.(html|shtml|php)$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That rule looks fine on first glance. Are you shure interpretation of `.htaccess` style files is enabled at all and that the file is located correctly? The next step then is to enable rewrite logging and check for the detailed steps inside your rewrite engine. This usually points out what is wrong.

Comment: He thanks for your help!The file is working as the other (the last) rewrite rule is working fine. How can I enable rewrite logging? I'm not that familiar with this...

Comment: For such questions your first look _always_ has to be at the official documentation. You _cannot_ code without consulting the documentations of the tools and utilities you use! http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Hee I have solved the probem. I have changed the order of first and the second rewrite rule. So rewrite rule for the maps comes first and rewrite rule for the url with "/" second. This is a bit strange and I would actually like to understand why is this happening, because now I don't...

Comment: As said: the way to find out what is happening why inside your rewrite engine is rewrite logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directives for mod_rewrite are read and processed from the top to the bottom. In your case you had the redirect in the top. This rules matches (sitemap.xml is not a file, or a directory, does not end with a slash, html, shtml or php). You add an extra slash to it, and redirect the request.

Now a new request comes in for `/sitemap.xml/`. The first rule does not match (ends with slash) and the second rule does not match (request does not end with `xml`, but with `xml/`). You serve a 404 error.

When switching the rules, the url (`/sitemap.xml`) is matched against the first rule, and matches. It is now rewritten. On the second pass the first rule does not match, and the second rule does not match (valid file).